# How to go inside a list of nested elements?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a nested component which returns a DOM list of tables. Each table contains `tbody`, `tr`, and `td`. And there are in total 20 tables.

Now, I want to go through all tables and check if one of them has a `td` with text "Something".

In JS I can get it like this:

```
let tableElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-test="myGridTest"] > div.x-panel-bodyWrap')[0].children.item(2).children.item(0).children.item(1).childNodes;
```

In DOM I get this:

[image]

And in Cypress I tried this:

```
cy.get('[data-test="myGridTest"] > div.x-panel-bodyWrap').children(2).children(0).children(1)
    .should('have.length', 20)
    .each(($li, index, $lis) => {
      return 'something else'
    })
    .then(($lis) => {
      expect($lis).to.have.text("Something")
    })
```

I don't know how can I chain `children()` because obviouisly `children(2).childen(0).children(1)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the HTML is visible, but if your plain JS is working, this should be a translation to Cypress

```js
cy.get('[data-test="myGridTest"] > div.x-panel-bodyWrap')  // querySelectorAll()
  .first()                                                 // [0]
  .children().eq(2)                                        // .children.item(2)
  .children().eq(0)                                        // .children.item(0)
  .children().eq(1)                                        // .children.item(1)
  .then($el => $el[0].childNodes)                          // .childNodes
```

`childNodes` is different to `children` in that it returns text nodes (spacing, newlines etc) as well as elements. There's no direct command, but you can drop down to Javascript in a callback.

---

```js
.each(($li, index, $lis) => {
  return 'something else'
})
```

Not sure what's going on with this loop, but you cannot return anything from inside except `true/false` to indicate `continue/early exit`. See docs.